# Multiple instrument chord

Tags: sound

I would like to create a chord using multiple instruments.  This started as an attempt to explain music to a friend but my curiosity has taken over.  I am familiar with the SoundNote function.

I know  that SoundNote can create a chord using the same instrument:

```
Sound[SoundNote[{"C4", "G3"}, 1, "Harpsichord"]]
```

And it can create a series of notes with different respective instruments:

```
Sound[{SoundNote["C", 0.5`, "Oboe"], SoundNote["G", 0.5`, "SynthVoice"], SoundNote["C5", 0.5`, "Organ"]}]
```

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to play more than one sound with specific notes at the same time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**This example in Documentation**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0e7lwomq-yz7ne) exactly answers your question. You just need to specify overlapping time intervals. Lets expand your specific case. Below after every second a new instrument will come in and they will all end at the same time.

```
Sound[{SoundNote["C", {0, 4}, "Oboe"], 
       SoundNote["G", {1, 4}, "SynthVoice"], 
       SoundNote["C5", {2, 4}, "Organ"], 
       SoundNote["E3", {3, 4}, "VoiceAahs"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Anyone ever made the Dr Who theme with Mathematica? (serious question)

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch if someone would dare - they need to read Chapter 9 of [Mathematica Cookbook by @SalMangano](http://mathematicacookbook.com/?page_id=35) - some excellent examples there.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch `Import["https://sites.google.com/site/thedoctorwhos/DoctorWho2005.mid"]` (Mathematica 9, Who knows about 8) :)